# looking to convert dictionary to data frame and csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that grabs time and price data from an api. I am looking to convert this to a dataframe, a csv, and ultimately the epoch to date time.

I have looked around a while and haven't found anything that has worked. a few seemingly unsolved appeared similar in structure.

The bottom few lines were my last attempt at creating a dataframe and it didn't yield any result or error message.

Any advice on how to turn this into something I can work with would be appreciated.

```py
def get_price_history(**kwargs):

    url = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{}/pricehistory'.format(kwargs.get('symbol'))

    params = {}
    params.update({'apikey': key})

    for arg in kwargs:
        parameter = {arg: kwargs.get(arg)}
        params.update(parameter)

    return requests.get(url, params=params).json()

    d = get_price_history(symbol='SPX',period=10,periodType='day',frequencyType='minute')

    pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['open', 'high','low','close','volume', 'datetime'])

    df.head(10)
```

Output of script from:

```
print(get_price_history(symbol='SPX',period=10,periodType='day',frequencyType='minute'),
```

Not above:

```
{
    'candles': [{
        'open': 3318.28,
        'high': 3320.6, 
        'low': 3317.77,
        'close': 3319.22,
        'volume': 0,
        'datetime': 1581345000000
    }, {
        'open': 3319.11,
        'high': 3320.5,
        'low': 3318.87,
        'close': 3320.46,
        'volume': 0,
        'datetime': 1581345060000
    },
```

Comment: look up json to csv formats, pandas can read json and then save csv. you can visualize the pandas dataframe to see whether the reading part was correct or not

Comment: The shown code would actually fail with an error because `df` isn't set. And the indentation also needs a repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df will fail because df was not assigned a value. Assuming the value of d will be your json output above, change your code to the below to import the json into a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['candles'], columns=['open', 'high','low','close','volume', 'datetime'])

print(df.head(2))

df.to_csv(r'file_location\\file_name.csv', index = True)
```

Save your df to csv using pd.to_csv